# Innertext not wrapping. SimpleHTMLDom

Tags: innertext

Wrapping the innertext after getting it out of a xml feed is not working for me. I was thinking something like this might work:

```
foreach($html->find('td',1) as $e) {
echo '<div style="width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">' . $e->innertext . '</div>';
}
```

but it's not wrapping. I am using Chrome to see the results. I have also tried to make the width smaller with no avail. It ends up cutting off the text and giving me a ... at the end. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you need to change in the jquery mobile css: .ui-li-desc { white-space: normal; }

Answer (score 1):

I used below snippet and works fine, `$html->find('td',1)`  this snippet does not return an array it returns object at index 1. Correct way; If you want deal with all "td" tags you should remove second parameter

```
$e = $html->find('td',1);
echo '<div style="width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">' . $e->innertext . '</div>';
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I wanted to get something from the table that has 3 <td> in it. I am grabbing the 2nd by using the 1 correct?

Comment: Yes, if there are only 3 td's in $html variable content then this is the correct way to do.

Comment: Did the solution worked for you? I have tried in my local, it worked fine.

Comment: Sort of. Not exactally what i was looking for. I needed a css change on the ul. View thus page http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/01/31/top-10-jquery-mobile-code-snippets-that-you-need-to-know/ look at .ui-li-desc { white-space: normal; } it is actually a jquery mobile style issue.